# get correct data from sorted by angular js div elements to modal, now it take just first elements data

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, sorting, bootstrap-modal

Get the correct data from sorted by angular js div elements to modal, now it take just first elements data:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
            <div class="product-thumb">
                <div class="caption" ng-repeat="car  in cars">
                    <h4>{{car.name}}</h4>
                    <p>{{car.date}}</p>
                    <p>{{car.price}} USD</p>
                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">{{car.name}}</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <p>{{car.date}}</p>
                                    <p>{{car.price}}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="button-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-   toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><i
                                class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span
                                class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-   md">Купити</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
JSvar app = angular.module('sorterApp', [])
.controller('carsController', ['$scope', 'orderByFilter', function ($scope, orderBy) {
    var cars = [
        {name: "Volvo", price: 3000, date: "2008/01"},
        {name: "BMW", price: 6500, date: "2010/02"},
        {name: "Saab", price: 2700, date: "2007/08"},
        {name: "Land Rover", price: 8200, date: "2012/09"},
        {name: "Skoda", price: 3000, date: "2009/11"},
        {name: "Deawoo", price: 1500, date: "2009/05"},
        {name: "Nissan", price: 6700, date: "2012/04"},
        {name: "Toyota", price: 7900, date: "2007/07"},
        {name: "Dacia", price: 1100, date: "2004/02"},
        {name: "Lada", price: 750, date: "1995/01"},
        {name: "Mercedes", price: 11000, date: "2013/08"},
        {name: "Bugatti", price: 35000, date: "2012/07"}
    ];

    var propertyName = null;
    $scope.propertyName = 'name';

    $scope.cars = orderBy(cars, $scope.propertyName);
    $scope.sortBy = function (propertyName) {

        $scope.cars = orderBy(cars, $scope.propertyName);
        $scope.propertyName = propertyName;

    };
}]);
```

Comment: Please proofread your question.  It is illegible at best.

Comment: How can i get сorrect data from sorted by angularjs div elements to modal window, now it take just first div element data

Comment: It is necessary that the pop-up window of a certain element displays its details

Comment: Not exactly an updated question with needed clarification.

Comment: how make  when i click on button near product list item and open bootstrap modal window - it contains data correct for this item (name, price, date)?Now it works just for first element of my product list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are giving each modal instance the same id "myModal".  These need to have unique id's which can be achieved like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal{{$index}}" role="dialog">
```

Then change the data-target on your button:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal{{$index}}">
```

Comment: jbrown - thank you very much for your help.it works now